# Django Tutorial 1

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I began to learn `Django`, now I'm creating my first app, I followed every step in the tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) but it doesn't work and it throws me the following error lines when doing `python manage.py runserver`:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7ffdfa76d8c0>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in          wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver         .py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426         , in check

    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75,          in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in          check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in          check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in          __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, i         n url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in          __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, i         n urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/home/boss/Descargas/Python-2.7.5/mysite/testsite/testsite/urls.py", line 21, in          <module>
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),

NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```

Comment: You probably forgot to `from django.conf.urls import include, url` at the top of your urls.py file

Comment: Please include source when asking these questions

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to import include in `mysite/urls.py`.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
```